# PowerShell 6.* Remoting using SSL certificate and UBUNTU

Tags: powershell, ubuntu, ssl, remoting

I have an UBUNTU 16.04 box (Let's call it **EARTH**) and Windows 2012 R2 box (Let's call it **MARS**). Using the below commands from the Windows box (**MARS**) I'm generating a self signed cert that I'm planning to use for PS Remoting.

**CMD1:**
$Cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertstoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName "myHost"

**CMD2:**
Export-Certificate -Cert $Cert -FilePath C:\temp\cert

On **MARS** (Windows box) there is a WSMAN listener created using the thumbprint of the self sign certificated that was just created.

**CMD3:** 
New-Item -Path WSMan:\LocalHost\Listener -Transport HTTPS -Address * -CertificateThumbPrint $Cert.Thumbprint –Force

I'm trying to initiate a PowerShell Remoting session from **EARTH** (UBUNTU box) to **MARS**

Does anyone know how to import the certificate into EARTH (UBUNTU server) so powershell can use it for the remoting session?

Source of PS Session: EARTH, the UBUNTU server

Target of PS Session: MARS, the windows 2012 R2 box from which the certificate was generated.

EARTH (UBUNTU server) is running PowerShell version 6.1 preview.2

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The export / Import certificate cmdlets are the targets for this use case.
As for Ubuntu, just use the cmdline on Ubuntu, see the Ubuntu forum discussion:

> In ubuntu:

1. - Go to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
2. - Create a new folder, i.e. "sudo mkdir school"
3. - Copy the .crt file into the school folder
4. - Make sure the permissions are OK (755 for the folder, 644 for the
     file)
5. - Run "sudo update-ca-certificates"

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/645818/how-to-install-certificates-for-command-line

Or the help info from Ubuntu directly.

> Installing the Certificate
>
> You can install the key file server.key and certificate file
>   server.crt, or the certificate file issued by your CA, by running
>   following commands at a terminal prompt:

```
sudo cp server.crt /etc/ssl/certs
sudo cp server.key /etc/ssl/private
```

> Now simply configure any applications, with the ability to use
>   public-key cryptography, to use the certificate and key files. For
>   example, Apache can provide HTTPS, Dovecot can provide IMAPS and
>   POP3S, etc.
>
> https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html

MS has provided step-by-step guidance on how to set this up and use it. Specifically the below directly addresses Ubuntu. This allows remoting without the additional certificate step you are using.

> PowerShell Remoting Over SSH
>
> Setup on Windows Machine
>
> 1. Install the latest PowerShell for Windows build from GitHub ◦You can tell if it has the SSH remoting support by looking at the
>      parameter sets for New-PSSession

```
Get-Command New-PSSession -syntax
New-PSSession [-Name <string[]>] [-HostName <string>] [-UserName <string>] [-KeyPath <string>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

> 2. Install the latest Win32 Open SSH build from GitHub using the installation instructions
> 3. Edit the sshd_config file at the location where you installed Win32 Open SSH ◦Make sure password authentication is enabled 
>      ◾PasswordAuthentication yes
>
> ◦Add a PowerShell subsystem entry
>   ◾Subsystem powershell

```
PowerShell_Install_Path\powershell.exe -sshs -NoLogo -NoProfile
```

> ◦Optionally enable key authentication
>   ◾RSAAuthentication yes
>   ◾PubkeyAuthentication yes
>
> 4.Restart the sshd service ◦Restart-Service sshd
>
> Setup on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) Machine:
>
> 1.Install the latest PowerShell for Linux build from GitHub ◦You can tell if it has the SSH remoting support by looking at the parameter
>   sets for New-PSSession

Get-Command New-PSSession -syntax
    New-PSSession [-Name ] [-HostName ] [-UserName ] [-KeyPath ] []

> 2.Install Ubuntu SSH as needed ◦sudo apt install openssh-client

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

> 3.Edit the sshd_config file at location /etc/ssh ◦Make sure password authentication is enabled 
>   ◾PasswordAuthentication yes
>
> ◦Add a PowerShell subsystem entry
>   ◾Subsystem powershell 
>       powershell -sshs -NoLogo -NoProfile
>
> ◦Optionally enable key authentication
>   ◾RSAAuthentication yes
>   ◾PubkeyAuthentication yes
>
> 4.Restart the sshd service ◦sudo service ssh restart
>
> PowerShell Remoting Example:
>
> The easiest way to test remoting is to just try it on a single
>   machine. Here I will create a remote session back to the same machine
>   on a Linux box. Notice that I am using PowerShell cmdlets from a
>   command prompt so we see prompts from ssh asking to verify the host
>   computer as well as password prompts. You can do the same thing on a
>   Windows machine to ensure remoting is working there and then remote
>   between machines by simply changing the host name.
>
> Linux to Linux

```
PS /home/TestUser> $session = New-PSSession -HostName UbuntuVM1 -UserName TestUser

The authenticity of host 'UbuntuVM1 (9.129.17.107)' cannot be established.

ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:2kCbnhT2dUE6WCGgVJ8Hyfu1z2wE4lifaJXLO7QJy0Y.

Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

TestUser@UbuntuVM1s password:

PS /home/TestUser> $session

 Id Name            ComputerName    ComputerType    State         ConfigurationName     Availability
 -- ----            ------------    ------------    -----         -----------------     ------------
  1 SSH1            UbuntuVM1       RemoteMachine   Opened        DefaultShell             Available
```

> https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/866b558771a20cca3daa47f300e830b31a24ee95/docs/new-features/remoting-over-ssh/README.md